# Gridlayout with ColumnSpec causing layout to use full screen width

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am using GridLayout with two columns and, for one of the rows, I want to insert a divider bar.  When I insert the bar, the layout becomes full screen width.  Without the bar it is behaving as I expect with WRAP_CONTENT.

I create the layout and all its content dynamically, not with XML.  Here's are the essentials:

```
private class ContentView extends GridLayout 
{
    ContentView (Context context) 
    {
        super (context);
        setColumnCount (2);
    }

    // adds "child" to the next cell in the layout
    public void addView (View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) 
    {
        super.addView (child, params);
        //... other code not shown ...
    }

    public void addDivider() 
    {
        int padding = (int) getResources().getDimension (R.dimen.normal_text_margin);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        params.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.height = (int) getResources().getDimension (R.dimen.divider_bar_height);
        params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec (0,2); // add to pair of columns
        View v = new View (getContext());
        v.setBackgroundColor (Color.BLACK);
        v.setPadding (padding, 0, padding, 0);
        v.setLayoutParams (params);
        super.addView (v, params);
    }
}
```

This is invoked by the following, where "v" is the GridLayout:

```
public View setContentView (ViewGroup v) 
{
    contentView = v;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    borderView.addView (contentView, params);
    return contentView;
}
```

If I comment-out the addDivider code, the layout is narrow.  When I enable the code, the layout is full screen width.  What attribute do I need to set differently to get the bar to not grow the layout width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to make this work using GridLayout (though I have to admit I did not spend time examining the source code).  Instead I wrote something very simple to do what I needed.

In case anyone else finds this code useful, here it is.  It allows multiple columns and rows where the width of each column is defined by the width of the widest member.  Likewise for row height.  And I added an api for inserting a row divider (just allows one divider, but you can expand on it to have multiples).

Also missing, because I don't need it right now, is layout params for each cell.  It left justifies the contents and centers it vertically.  Also missing is cell padding.  Like I said, a simple implementation.  But easy to enhance.

```
public class SimpleGridLayout extends ViewGroup
{
  private Paint barPaint;

  int cols = 0;
  int[] colWidths = null;
  int[] rowHeights = null;
  int dividerRow = -1; // only allow one divider row, keep implementation simple
  int dividerHeight = 0; // pixels
  int dividerMargin = 0; // pixels
  int yDivider = 0;

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public SimpleGridLayout (Context context)
  {
    super (context);
    barPaint = new Paint(); // for painting insertion line
    dividerHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.divider_bar_height);
    dividerMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.divider_bar_margin);
    setWillNotDraw (false);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
  {
    // clear column widths, create height array
    for (int i = 0;  i < cols;  i++)
      colWidths[i] = 0;
    rowHeights = new int [(getChildCount() + cols - 1) / cols]; // account for partial row

    // determine column widths, working from left to right
    int widthAvailable = MeasureSpec.getSize (widthMeasureSpec);
    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < cols;  iCol++)
    {
      // visit each row
      for (int i = iCol, iRow = 0, limit = getChildCount();  i < limit;  i += cols, iRow++)
      {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        int itemWidthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec (widthAvailable, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int itemHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec (0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        child.measure (itemWidthSpec, itemHeightSpec);

        colWidths [iCol] = Math.max (colWidths [iCol], child.getMeasuredWidth());
        rowHeights [iRow] = Math.max (rowHeights [iRow], child.getMeasuredHeight());
      }

      widthAvailable -= colWidths [iCol];
    }

    // get total width
    int width = 0;
    for (int i = 0;  i < cols;  i++)
      width += colWidths [i];

    // get total height
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0;  i < rowHeights.length;  i++)
      height += rowHeights [i];

    if (dividerRow != -1)
      height += dividerHeight;

    setMeasuredDimension (width, height);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @Override
  protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
  {
    // layout each column, working from left to right
    int xCol = 0;
    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < cols;  iCol++)
    {
      int yRow = 0;

      // visit each row
      for (int i = iCol, iRow = 0, limit = getChildCount();  i < limit;  i += cols, iRow++)
      {
        View child = getChildAt(i);

        if (iRow == dividerRow)
        {
          yDivider = yRow;
          yRow += dividerHeight;
        }

        // left justify
        int left = xCol;

        // center vertically
        int dyRow = rowHeights [iRow];
        int top = yRow + (dyRow - child.getMeasuredHeight()) / 2;

        int right = left + child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int bottom = top + child.getMeasuredHeight();
        child.layout (left, top, right, bottom);

        yRow += rowHeights [iRow];
      }

      xCol += colWidths [iCol];
    }
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @Override
  protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)
  {
    barPaint.setColor (getResources().getColor (R.color.divider_bar));
    canvas.drawRect (dividerMargin,
                     yDivider,
                     getWidth() - 2*dividerMargin,
                     yDivider + dividerHeight,
                     barPaint);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @Override
  public void addView (View v, LayoutParams params)
  {
    super.addView (v, params);
    rowHeights = null;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public void addDivider ()
  {
    rowHeights = null;
    dividerRow = (getChildCount() + 1) / cols;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public void setColumnCount (int cols)
  {
    this.cols = cols;
    colWidths = new int[cols];
  }
}
```